# What is this thing on a FDX MD11 (MD10?)?

Tags: feature-identification, sensors, md-11

[image]I assume something forward looking; not sure why there and how they got this to play nicely with radar

Comment: Is this the only photo you have of it? It looks like a birdstrike from here.

Comment: why was there a military bloke standing around at fedex ?

Comment: @Fattie I believe that is the governor of New Hampshire, Chris Sununu, speaking, likely receiving a shipment of medical supplies to fight COVID.  (Based on the seal on the podium, and a quick google search for the NH governor and extrapolating to current events.)  The uniformed officer is probably part of the National Guard or maybe his protection detail.  This is just a guess though.

Comment: thanks for that @DarrelHoffman

Answer (score 17):

It's the infrared sensor for the Enhanced Flight Vision System (EFVS).

From FedEx [Newsroom](https://newsroom.fedex.com/newsroom/fedex-express-earns-faa-certification-for-innovative-flight-safety-system/) June 23, 2008:

> FedEx Express is the first major commercial carrier in the airline
> industry to receive a Supplemental Type Certificate from the FAA for
> the advanced system, authorizing its installation in the company’s
> fleet of Boeing MD-10 freighters. The company’s goal for the system is
> to improve the level of flight safety by increasing visibility of
> pilots during adverse weather conditions and darkness.
>
> A unique application of Honeywell International “Head Up Display”
> (HUD) technology combined with infrared “Enhanced Flight Vision
> System” (EFVS) technology of Elbit Systems of America Commercial
> Aviation-Kollsman Business Unit, positions the system as the leader in
> the avionic visual technologies market.
>
> The Honeywell HUD interfaces with aircraft navigational and flight
> data systems in presenting a high resolution liquid crystal display of
> critical flight guidance information. This is overlaid with real-time
> EFVS infrared video of the outside world that is displayed in an
> overhead unit in the captain’s forward field of view using
> state-of-the-art HUD “combiner” technology. Elbit Systems Ltd.,
> Electro-Optics-Elop manufactures the combiner glass.

The combined image appears like this:
[image: EFVS-HUD]

Source: FedEx

Comment: I was wondering, is that a "your head moves and it tracks your head/eyeballs and paints appropriately" type of HUD, or is it the type where you "have to keep your head in the correct spot" ??

Comment: It's a fixed combiner glass.  The pilot adjusts the seat to put their head within the 'eyebox' so that the projected image aligns with the outside world.  It does not try to track the pilot's head or eyes.

Comment: thanks for that explanation, good one

Comment: @Fattie, HUDs have, generally, been properly aligning with the outside, passively without tracking anything, since their beginnings as [reflector sights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflector_sight) in 1900! The mechanism is fairly simple: the display is projected to infinity using lenses and the adjusted image reflected off a half-mirror that is the screen. That way the image is properly aligned from anywhere it is visible, so the pilot just needs to keep their head in appropriate range, but not exact spot.

Comment: @Fattie, … note that the collimator is needed so that both the real world in the distance and the HUD image are seen sharp by the pilot. If the pilot was just looking through a semi-transparent display, they'd either see the distant objects sharply or the display sharply, but not both at the same time as one would be out of focus. This is fixed by projecting the image to infinity – with the nice bonus of providing the alignment.

Comment: @JanHudec got you now and thanks!